# AngularJS with Typescript and Webpack managing dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack, tsconfig

My team is tasked with migrating an AngularJS application to use Webpack as a build system combined with TypeScript. This is all done as a prep to gradually move an application from AngularJS to Angular. (We are following migration guides provided by the Angular team)

Today I ran into an issue with TypeScript's 'Import' statement and I can't seem to find the reason for it. I found a solution, but want to know why this is the case.

In this test run I am having 2 modules in 2 different files. **AuthModule** and **LoginModule** . I think their dependency is Circular in that **AuthModule** -> **LoginModule** -> **AuthModule**

```
//in auth.module.js (this module is loaded before LoginModule)
import {LoginModule} from './login.module'; //is just an exported string

const authModule = angular.module('auth.module', [LoginModule])';
...


//in login.module.js
import {AuthModule} from './auth.module'; //again just an exported string

const LoginModule = angular.module('login.module', [AuthModule]);
...
```

Those are just 2 small snippets and this built and when viewed in the browser everything was working fine.

However, the moment I converted the files to TypeScript it did not seem to like that circular dependency. The app built in webpack without errors, but bombed in the browser.

To fix it I needed to not 'Import' **AuthModule** in **LoginModule** and when providing the dependency to the LoginModule I needed to provide a local string instead of the imported String.

```
//in login.module.ts (don't import AuthModule)
const LoginModule = angular.module('login.module', ['auth.module']); //just provide the name of the module here as a string
...
```

This builds and works fine and I am fine with that, but want to understand why. What is the difference between a TypeScript import and a 'webpack' import. My **.tsconfig** module property is set to **CommonJS** . Is that why?

Comment: What error did you get in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, when you are importing the LoginModule you are importing an instance of that LoginModule, thus angular.js throw an error. Instead you need to provide a string inside that module declaration, that's why it's working.